# How can I pass objects to a matrix in a GitHub Action?

Tags: javascript, object, github-actions

I have a JavaScript GitHub action which outputs a simple array of objects, like so:

```
[
  {
    prop1: val1a,
    prop2: val2a,
    prop3: val3a
  },
  {
    prop1: val1b,
    prop2: val2b,
    prop3: val3b
  }
]
```

In a new job, I'd like to read in this array, loop over it, and print the property values during each iteration of the loop. How is that done, especially the last part?

With the code below, I've managed to create a new job, and have it loop over each element in the array.  But during each iteration, how can I access the property values of each element?

Thanks in advance.

---

**My Code**

*myAction.yml*

```
name: GitHub Actions Demo
on: [push]
jobs:
  job1:
    outputs:
      matrix: ${{ steps.hello.outputs.matrix }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout
        uses: actions/checkout@v2.3.4
        with:
          fetch-depth: 0
      - name: Test JS action # Run the JavaScript action to output an array of objects.
        id: hello
        uses: ghusername/myreponame@master

  # Run the second job here, to read in the output of the previous job, set its value to a matrix, then iterate over that matrix.
  job2:
    needs: [job1]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    strategy:
      matrix: ${{fromJSON(needs.job1.outputs.matrix)}}
    steps:
      - run: echo "I want to outputted objects from job1 to print here"
```

*myJavaScriptAction.js (located on GitHub at ghusername/myreponame@master*

```
const core = require("@actions/core");
 
const myArr = [
  {
    prop1: 111,
    prop2: 222,
    prop3: 333
  },
  {
    prop1: 444,
    prop2: 555,
    prop3: 666
  }
]

/* Convert output array to valid JSON, then stringify it. This is required in order to pass it to the next GitHub action.*/
outputArr = {
  include: myArr,
};
core.setOutput(
  "matrix",
  JSON.stringify(outputArr)
);
```

Comment: It could be related to the fact that you used `Job-1` instead of `job1` on the job2 matrix: `matrix: ${{fromJSON(needs.Job-1.outputs.matrix)}}`. Here is a reference you might found interesting: https://github.community/t/how-to-share-matrix-between-jobs/128595

Comment: OK thanks very much for the reply . The `Job-` vs. `job1` issue is just an unrelated typo that I made while copying my code to my Stack Overflow post. But the link you posted does indeed show me how to do what I want.  Why don't you post that in an actual reply to this question, and I can mark it as the answer? That way you get the credit :-)